# Theory of Computation: Design a 2-stack PDA for this language?

Tags: theory, computation

Consider a language L2 = { ak bk ck | k >= 0 }.

(k should be superscript)

Design a 2-stack PDA for the language L2.

Could anyone give me some guidance on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Get a textbook from your library, and read it, or google out a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try solving the case with a 1-stack PDA and the language `{ aⁿ bⁿ | n >= 0 }` - that should expose how to solve `{ aⁿ bⁿ cⁿ| n >= 0 }` using an additional stack.